# Exact form of two-time correlators in out of equilibrium evolution from factorized distributions

Tags: density-operator, correlation-functions, non-equilibrium

Suppose that the have an initial product state at some time $t=0$ written in a computational basis $|0\rangle,|1\rangle$, for instance the state $|1011010\rangle$. The associated density matrix $\rho_0$ in this case is a trivial one, with all entries being 0 except one entry equal to 1 in the diagonal.

Now, suppose we have a Hamiltonian $H$ to evolve this state to a later time $t$, and that for two operators $A,B$ that are **diagonal** in the $|0\rangle,|1\rangle$ basis, we want to compute the correlation:
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle A(t)B(0)\rangle=\text{Tr}\left(A U(t)\left[B\rho_0\right]\right),
\end{eqnarray}
where $U(t)[X]$ is the propagator defined by the equation of motion, and we have used the quantum regression theorem in the equation. Is this equivalent to:
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle A(t)B(0)\rangle=\text{Tr}\left(A U(t)\left[B\rho_0\right]\right)=\text{Tr}\left(Ae^{-iHt}\rho_0' e^{iHt}\right)=\text{Tr}\left(A(t)\rho_0 '\right)
\end{eqnarray}
where in the last step we used the cyclic property of traces. That is, can we generally write the correlators in the above form by assuming replacing $\rho_0'=B\rho_0$? In that case, since $B$ is diagonal in the computational basis (and so is $\rho_0$), this would change the initial distribution by a phase only, and the correlation reduces to the expectation value of $A(t)$ with an additional phase factor.

Is the above statement correct?